# Can array lengths be inferred in Rust?

Tags: rust

I can do this:

```
let a: [f32; 3] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
```

But why doesn't this work?

```
let a: [f32; _] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
```

It seems to me that the length is redundant and trivial to infer. Is there a way to avoid having to specify it explicitly? (And without having to append `f32` to all the literals.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`_` can only be used in two contexts: in patterns, to match a value to ignore, and as a placeholder for a type. In array types, the length is not a type, but an expression, and `_` cannot be used in expressions.

What you can do, though, is append `f32` to only one of the literals and omit the type completely. Since all the items of an array must have the same type, the compiler will infer the correct element type for the array.

```
let a = [0.0f32, 1.0, 2.0];
```

Comment: If you are dealing with constants or static variables (and you have to specify the type) it's common to use a slice type instead: `static FOO: &[f32] = &[3.0, ...];`

Comment: then you can use a `const`, unless you need to have the slice itself in static memory (i.e if you need a `&'static &[f32]`).

Answer (score 7):

Since 1.39 it's possible using a simple macro

```
macro_rules! arr {
    ($id: ident $name: ident: [$ty: ty; _] = $value: expr) => {
        $id $name: [$ty; $value.len()] = $value;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
arr!(static BYTES: [u8; _] = *b"foo");
arr!(let floats: [f32; _] = [0., 1.]);
```

Comment: Version with visibility and doc comments preserved: https://gist.github.com/MingweiSamuel/3d6542a8dde4546a19d98b392237514b

Comment: Note this evaluates `$value` twice.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman since this makes `$value` the length of an array type, `$value` has to be `const`, and I think that means we don't have to worry about multiple evaluations.

Answer (score 7):

It is now possible on nightly with the [`generic_arg_infer`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/85077) feature, for both the type and the initializer:

```rust
#![feature(generic_arg_infer)]

let _arr: [f32; _] = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
let _arr: [f32; 3] = [0.0; _];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with constants or static variables (and you have to specify the type) it's common to use a slice type instead:

```
static FOO: &[f32] = &[0.0, 1.0, 2.0];
```

---

<sub>This was originally a comment by [Lukas Kalbertodt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2408867/lukas-kalbertodt) to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40107874).</sub>

Comment: That's a fundamentally different type though. Doesn't have compile time constant length.