# What is an underscore in rust-analyzer's type hints for array size?

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

I am a Rust beginner, please bear with me.

As you can see in the image below, VS Code [rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer) prompts a type hint with an underscore "_" in the size part. What is it?

```rust
let a: [i32; _] = [3; 5];
// this is the same as
let a: [i32; _] = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3];
```

[image: the same code with type annotations [i32; _] automatically inserted by VSCode]

Comment: I don't think this question is the same as the linked one. In _this_ post, the underscore is displayed by `rust-analyzer` as [type hints](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#inlay-hints). In _that_ post, underscore is one of many [operators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html) allowed by Rust syntax.

Comment: Here the underscore simply says `rust-analyzer` could not figure out the array length, which **is already fixed** as of this comment. See patches and discussions on GitHub [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/pull/8799) and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-analyzer/pull/8813).

Answer (score 3):

VS Code is cheating here.

When a type is expected, `_` means that the compiler must infer the type. For example:

```rust
let v: [_; 5] = [3; 5];
    //  ^ infers type for usage

f(&v); // where f: fn(&[u8])
       // the previous type will be inferred to `u8`
```

However, this is only possible where a *type* is expected. `[T; _]` is *not* valid Rust:

```rust
let foo: [i32; _] = [1, 2];
```

gives

```
error: expected expression, found reserved identifier `_`
 --> src/main.rs:2:20
  |
1 | let foo: [i32; _] = [1, 2];
  |     ---        ^ expected expression
  |     |
  |     while parsing the type for `foo`
```

But VS Code uses this anyway as a way to say "I don't know the value here" as while this is not valid Rust, it is a well understood concept.

See also:

- [What does it mean to instantiate a Rust generic with an underscore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37215739/what-does-it-mean-to-instantiate-a-rust-generic-with-an-underscore?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What is Vec<_>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363984/what-is-vec?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Can array lengths be inferred in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107797/can-array-lengths-be-inferred-in-rust)